How to detect when a key is played on a musical keyboard
I have a musical keyboard (Casio CTK3500) which has an USB B to A output. I want to know a way to connect one (or more) of the wires from the USB cable to Arduino so that it can detect when a key is being played on the keyboard (maybe by detecting a voltage change, but I cannot seem to detect enough voltage change to do that).
I don't need to know which key is being played or anything like that. I just want to detect when a key is being played on the keyboard.
Any help is much appreciated.

USB is a complete (and also complex) communication protocol. You cannot just monitor one line for voltage changes. You would need a USB host chip and write the driver software, that is able to handle this specific USB device. That is not an easy and fast task to do. What happens, when you connect the keyboard to a PC? As what kind of device does it enumerate in the device manager (assuming Windows here)? Do you need special drivers for it to work, or does it work with Windows out of the box?

If it behaves like a normal MIDI device on USB, then this question might be relevant

Check out this item entitled 'Get input from USB musical keyboard to Arduino digital input' @ https://forum.arduino.cc/t/get-input-from-usb-musical-keyboard-to-arduino-digital-input/1265142

" I just want to detect when a key is being played on the keyboard." ... then it may be easier to crack open the keyboard and solder some wires between it and the Arduino. But is that what I would do? No, I'd grab a Linux computer (like a Raspberry Pi), install the USB MIDI drivers and monitor the output. The latter would be a lot easier then trying to figure out how to cleverly use an Arduino. And by "clever" I mean surmount all the problems you will encounter using an Arduino. Starting with finding an Arduino with a HOST USB PORT.

if you just want to detect a key press, use the headphone jack; it will have (ac) voltage on it when a key is pressed.

There is absolutely no way you can "detect a voltage change" in a USB signal to tell you whether or not a key is being pressed. The USB protocol is quite complex, see USB communications. Basically zeroes and ones are being transmitted very quickly at at least 1.5 Mbit/s.
The keyboard you mention appears to have a MIDI port. That is much more likely to be usable to see if keys are being pressed.
I did a post a while ago about a MIDI decoder which would let you detect things like that.
Example code here:
//  MIDI_decoder
//  
//  Author:  Nick Gammon
//  Date:    11th April 2012.
//  Version: 1.2
//  Released into the public domain.

//  Version 1.1: Amended to allow for repeated parameters to the same channel message
//    eg. 0x90 0x45 0x46 0x47 0x48 does a "note on" for two notes
//  Version 1.2: Removed "repeating" for system messages.
//  Version 1.3: Amended to allow for RealTime messages to be ignored

#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Streaming.h>

// Plug MIDI into pin D2 (MIDI in serial)

SoftwareSerial midi (2, 3);  // Rx, Tx

#define MESSAGE(which, desc) const char control_ ## which [] PROGMEM = desc; 
  
MESSAGE (0, "Bank Select (MSB)");
MESSAGE (1, "Modulation Wheel or Lever (MSB)");
MESSAGE (2, "Breath Controller (MSB)");
MESSAGE (3, "Undefined (MSB)");
MESSAGE (4, "Foot Controller (MSB)");
MESSAGE (5, "Portamento Time (MSB)");
MESSAGE (6, "Data Entry (MSB) (MSB)");
MESSAGE (7, "Channel Volume (formerly Main Volume) (MSB)");
MESSAGE (8, "Balance (MSB)");
MESSAGE (9, "Undefined:9 (MSB)");
MESSAGE (10, "Pan (MSB)");
MESSAGE (11, "Expression Controller (MSB)");
MESSAGE (12, "Effect Control 1 (MSB)");
MESSAGE (13, "Effect Control 2 (MSB)");
MESSAGE (14, "Undefined (MSB)");
MESSAGE (15, "Undefined (MSB)");
MESSAGE (16, "General Purpose Controller 1 (MSB)");
MESSAGE (17, "General Purpose Controller 2 (MSB)");
MESSAGE (18, "General Purpose Controller 3 (MSB)");
MESSAGE (19, "General Purpose Controller 4 (MSB)");
MESSAGE (20, "Undefined:20 (MSB)");
MESSAGE (21, "Undefined:21 (MSB)");
MESSAGE (22, "Undefined:22 (MSB)");
MESSAGE (23, "Undefined:23 (MSB)");
MESSAGE (24, "Undefined:24 (MSB)");
MESSAGE (25, "Undefined:25 (MSB)");
MESSAGE (26, "Undefined:26 (MSB)");
MESSAGE (27, "Undefined:27 (MSB)");
MESSAGE (28, "Undefined:28 (MSB)");
MESSAGE (29, "Undefined:29 (MSB)");
MESSAGE (30, "Undefined:30 (MSB)");
MESSAGE (31, "Undefined:31 (MSB)");
MESSAGE (32, "Bank Select (LSB)");
MESSAGE (33, "Modulation Wheel or Lever (LSB)");
MESSAGE (34, "Breath Controller (LSB)");
MESSAGE (35, "Undefined:35 (LSB)");
MESSAGE (36, "Foot Controller (LSB)");
MESSAGE (37, "Portamento Time (LSB)");
MESSAGE (38, "Data Entry (LSB)");
MESSAGE (39, "Channel Volume, formerly Main Volume (LSB)");
MESSAGE (40, "Balance (LSB)");
MESSAGE (41, "Undefined:41 (LSB)");
MESSAGE (42, "Pan (LSB)");
MESSAGE (43, "Expression Controller (LSB)");
MESSAGE (44, "Effect control 1 (LSB)");
MESSAGE (45, "Effect control 2 (LSB)");
MESSAGE (46, "Undefined:46 (LSB)");
MESSAGE (47, "Undefined:47 (LSB)");
MESSAGE (48, "General Purpose Controller 1 (LSB)");
MESSAGE (49, "General Purpose Controller 2 (LSB)");
MESSAGE (50, "General Purpose Controller 3 (LSB)");
MESSAGE (51, "General Purpose Controller 4 (LSB)");
MESSAGE (52, "Undefined:52 (LSB)");
MESSAGE (53, "Undefined:53 (LSB)");
MESSAGE (54, "Undefined:54 (LSB)");
MESSAGE (55, "Undefined:55 (LSB)");
MESSAGE (56, "Undefined:56 (LSB)");
MESSAGE (57, "Undefined:57 (LSB)");
MESSAGE (58, "Undefined:58 (LSB)");
MESSAGE (59, "Undefined:59 (LSB)");
MESSAGE (60, "Undefined:60 (LSB)");
MESSAGE (61, "Undefined:61 (LSB)");
MESSAGE (62, "Undefined:62 (LSB)");
MESSAGE (63, "Undefined:63 (LSB)");
MESSAGE (64, "Damper Pedal on/off (Sustain): < 64 is off, otherwise on");
MESSAGE (65, "Portamento On/Off: < 64 is off, otherwise on");
MESSAGE (66, "Sostenuto On/Off: < 64 is off, otherwise on");
MESSAGE (67, "Soft Pedal On/Off: < 64 is off, otherwise on");
MESSAGE (68, "Legato Footswitch: < 64 is Normal, otherwise Legato");
MESSAGE (69, "Hold 2: < 64 is off, otherwise on");
MESSAGE (70, "Sound Controller 1 (default: Sound Variation) (LSB)");
MESSAGE (71, "Sound Controller 2 (default: Timbre/Harmonic Intens.) (LSB)");
MESSAGE (72, "Sound Controller 3 (default: Release Time) (LSB)");
MESSAGE (73, "Sound Controller 4 (default: Attack Time) (LSB)");
MESSAGE (74, "Sound Controller 5 (default: Brightness) (LSB)");
MESSAGE (75, "Sound Controller 6 (default: Decay Time - see MMA RP-021) (LSB)");
MESSAGE (76, "Sound Controller 7 (default: Vibrato Rate - see MMA RP-021) (LSB)");
MESSAGE (77, "Sound Controller 8 (default: Vibrato Depth - see MMA RP-021) (LSB)");
MESSAGE (78, "Sound Controller 9 (default: Vibrato Delay - see MMA RP-021) (LSB)");
MESSAGE (79, "Sound Controller 10 (default undefined - see MMA RP-021) (LSB)");
MESSAGE (80, "General Purpose Controller 5 (LSB)");
MESSAGE (81, "General Purpose Controller 6 (LSB)");
MESSAGE (82, "General Purpose Controller 7 (LSB)");
MESSAGE (83, "General Purpose Controller 8 (LSB)");
MESSAGE (84, "Portamento Control (LSB)");
MESSAGE (85, "Undefined:85");
MESSAGE (86, "Undefined:86");
MESSAGE (87, "Undefined:87");
MESSAGE (88, "High Resolution Velocity Prefix (LSB)");
MESSAGE (89, "Undefined:89");
MESSAGE (90, "Undefined:90");
MESSAGE (91, "Effects 1 Depth");
MESSAGE (92, "Effects 2 Depth (formerly Tremolo Depth)");
MESSAGE (93, "Effects 3 Depth");
MESSAGE (94, "Effects 4 Depth (formerly Celeste [Detune] Depth)");
MESSAGE (95, "Effects 5 Depth (formerly Phaser Depth)");
MESSAGE (96, "Data Increment (Data Entry +1) (see MMA RP-018)");
MESSAGE (97, "Data Decrement (Data Entry -1) (see MMA RP-018)");
MESSAGE (98, "Non-Registered Parameter Number (NRPN) - (LSB)");
MESSAGE (99, "Non-Registered Parameter Number (NRPN) - (MSB)");
MESSAGE (100, "Registered Parameter Number (RPN) - (LSB)");
MESSAGE (101, "Registered Parameter Number (RPN) - (MSB)");
MESSAGE (102, "Undefined:102");
MESSAGE (103, "Undefined:103");
MESSAGE (104, "Undefined:104");
MESSAGE (105, "Undefined:105");
MESSAGE (106, "Undefined:106");
MESSAGE (107, "Undefined:107");
MESSAGE (108, "Undefined:108");
MESSAGE (109, "Undefined:109");
MESSAGE (110, "Undefined:110");
MESSAGE (111, "Undefined:111");
MESSAGE (112, "Undefined:112");
MESSAGE (113, "Undefined:113");
MESSAGE (114, "Undefined:114");
MESSAGE (115, "Undefined:115");
MESSAGE (116, "Undefined:116");
MESSAGE (117, "Undefined:117");
MESSAGE (118, "Undefined:118");
MESSAGE (119, "Undefined:119");
MESSAGE (120, "All Sound Off");
MESSAGE (121, "Reset All Controllers");
MESSAGE (122, "Local Control On/Off: 0 off, 127 on");
MESSAGE (123, "All Notes Off");
MESSAGE (124, "Omni Mode Off (+ all notes off)");
MESSAGE (125, "Omni Mode On (+ all notes off)");
MESSAGE (126, "Mono Mode On (+ poly off, + all notes off)");
MESSAGE (127, "Poly Mode On (+ mono off, +all notes off)");

const char * const messagesTable [128] PROGMEM =
{   
control_0, control_1, control_2, control_3, control_4, 
control_5, control_6, control_7, control_8, control_9, 
control_10, control_11, control_12, control_13, control_14, 
control_15, control_16, control_17, control_18, control_19, 
control_20, control_21, control_22, control_23, control_24, 
control_25, control_26, control_27, control_28, control_29, 
control_30, control_31, control_32, control_33, control_34, 
control_35, control_36, control_37, control_38, control_39, 
control_40, control_41, control_42, control_43, control_44, 
control_45, control_46, control_47, control_48, control_49, 
control_50, control_51, control_52, control_53, control_54, 
control_55, control_56, control_57, control_58, control_59, 
control_60, control_61, control_62, control_63, control_64, 
control_65, control_66, control_67, control_68, control_69, 
control_70, control_71, control_72, control_73, control_74, 
control_75, control_76, control_77, control_78, control_79, 
control_80, control_81, control_82, control_83, control_84, 
control_85, control_86, control_87, control_88, control_89, 
control_90, control_91, control_92, control_93, control_94, 
control_95, control_96, control_97, control_98, control_99, 
control_100, control_101, control_102, control_103, control_104, 
control_105, control_106, control_107, control_108, control_109, 
control_110, control_111, control_112, control_113, control_114, 
control_115, control_116, control_117, control_118, control_119, 
control_120, control_121, control_122, control_123, control_124, 
control_125, control_126, control_127
};  // end of messagesTable
  
const int noRunningStatus = -1;

int runningStatus;
unsigned long lastRead;
byte lastCommand;

void setup() {
  //  Set MIDI baud rate:
  midi.begin(31250);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println ();
  Serial.println (F("MIDI Decoder. Author: Nick Gammon."));
  runningStatus = noRunningStatus;
} // end of setup

void RealTimeMessage (const byte msg)
  {
    
  } // end of RealTimeMessage
  
// get next byte from serial (blocks)
int getNext ()
  {

  if (runningStatus != noRunningStatus)
    {
    int c = runningStatus;
    // finished with look ahead
    runningStatus = noRunningStatus;
    return c;
    }
    
  while (true)
    {
    while (midi.available () == 0)
      {}
    byte c = midi.read ();
    if (c >= 0xF8)  // RealTime messages
      RealTimeMessage (c);
    else
      return c;
    }
  } // end of getNext

const char * notes [] = { "C ", "C#", "D ", "D#", "E ", "F ", "F#", "G ", "G#", "A ", "A#", "B " };

// interpret a note in terms of note name and octave
const char * getNote ()
  {
  byte note = getNext ();
  byte octave = note / 12;
  Serial << notes [note % 12] << F("(") << _DEC (octave - 1) << F(")");
  return " "; 
  }  // end of getNote
  
// dump a system exclusive message in hex
void showSystemExclusive ()
  {
  int count = 0;
  while (true)
    {
    while (midi.available () == 0)
      {}
    byte c = midi.read ();
    if (c >= 0x80)
      {
      Serial << endl;
      runningStatus = c;
      return;  
      }
    
    Serial << _HEX (c) << " ";
    if (++count > 32)
      {
      Serial << endl;
      count = 0;  
      }
    } // end of reading until all system exclusive done
  }  // end of showSystemExclusive
  
/* Print a string from Program Memory directly to save RAM */
void printProgStr (const char * str)
{
  char c;
  if(!str) return;
  while((c = pgm_read_byte(str++)))
    Serial.print(c);
} // end of printProgStr

// show a control message by looking up in the table
void showControlMessage ()
  {
   byte message =  getNext () & 0x7F;
   byte param = getNext ();
   // get address from progmem, display each byte
   printProgStr ((const char *) pgm_read_word(&(messagesTable[message])));
   // show parameter in hex
   Serial << ": 0x" << _HEX (param) << endl;
  }  // end of showControlMessage
  
void loop() 
{
  byte c = getNext ();

  if (((c & 0x80) == 0) && (lastCommand & 0x80))
    {
    runningStatus = c;
    c = lastCommand; 
    }
    
  // channel is in low order bits
  int channel = (c & 0x0F) + 1;

  // show time since last message in microseconds
  char buf [15];
  ltoa (micros () - lastRead, buf, 10);
  byte spaces = 10 - strlen (buf);
  for (byte i = 0; i < spaces; i++)
    Serial << " ";
  
  // show elapsed time
  Serial << buf << ": ";  
  lastRead = micros ();
    
  // messages start with high-order bit set
  if (c & 0x80)
    {
    lastCommand = c;
    switch ((c >> 4) & 0x07)
      {
      case 0: 
        Serial << F("Note off channel = ") << channel << F(", note = ") << getNote () << F(", velocity = ") << getNext () << endl;
        break;
        
      case 1: 
        Serial << F("Note  on channel = ") << channel << F(", note = ") << getNote () << F(", velocity = ") << getNext () << endl;
        break;
        
      case 2: 
        Serial << F("Polyphonic pressure channel = ") << channel << F(", note = ") << getNote () << F(", pressure = ") << getNext () << endl;
        break;
        
      case 3: 
        Serial << F("Control change channel = ") << channel << ", ";
        showControlMessage ();
        break;
        
      case 4: 
        Serial << F("Program change channel = ") << channel << F(", program = ") << getNext () << endl;
        break;
        
      case 5: 
        Serial << F("After-touch pressure channel = ") << channel << F(", value = ") << getNext () << endl;
        break;
        
      case 6: 
        Serial << F("Pitch wheel change channel = ") << channel << F(", value = ") << (getNext () | getNext () << 7) << endl;
        break;
        
      case 7:  // system message
        {
        lastCommand = 0;           // these won't repeat I don't think
        Serial << "System: ";
        switch (c & 0x0F)
          {
          case 0:
            Serial << F("Exclusive (in hex)") << F(", vendor ID = ") << getNext () << endl;
            showSystemExclusive ();
            break;
            
          case 1:
            Serial << F("Time code: value/type = ") << getNext () << endl;
            break;
          
          case 2: 
            Serial << F("Song position pointer, value = ") << (getNext () | getNext () << 7) << endl;
            break;
          
          case 3:
            Serial << F("Song select, song = ") << getNext () << endl;
            break;

          case 4:
            Serial << F("Reserved (4)") << endl;
            break;

          case 5:
            Serial << F("Reserved (5)") << endl;
            break;

          case 6:
            Serial << F("Tune request") << endl;
            break;

          case 7:
            Serial << F("End of exclusive") << endl;
            break;
            
          case 8:
            Serial << F("Timing clock") << endl;
            break;
            
          case 9:
            Serial << F("Reserved (9)") << endl;
            break;

          case 10:
            Serial << F("Start") << endl;
            break;
            
          case 11:
            Serial << F("Continue") << endl;
            break;
            
          case 12:
            Serial << F("Stop") << endl;
            break;
            
          case 13:
            Serial << F("Reserved (13)") << endl;
            break;
            
          case 14:
            Serial << F("Active sensing") << endl;
            break;
            
          case 15:
            Serial << F("Reset") << endl;
            break;
            
          }  // end of switch on system message  
          
        }  // end system message
        break;
      }  // end of switch
    }  // end of if
  else
    Serial << _HEX(c) << endl;
   
}  // end of loop

You need a modest amount of hardware to convert the MIDI signal into something you can plug into the Arduino.

